# Agrupamento de RadioButton no Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Todos dizem que basta colocar um objeto container(Panel, Groupbox e etc) e dentro dele os controles RadioButton que o container agrupa. Porem, não tem como trabalhar com a propriedade ItemIndex por exemplo, até porque o Groupbox não possui essa prop. Há uma forma de agrupar controles Radiobutton, mas de forma a trabalhar com eles, como sendo um agrupamento só e não tê-los em um local único e fazer tudo individualmente, controle a controle. Há como?

Comment: Como assim confusa. Ter um controle único para radiobutton, como em modo web temos o RadiobuttonList, ou seja, trabalhar com a propriedade ItemIndex ou SelectedItem, tipo assim, mas com Radiobutton. Para dizer a verdade, estou abandonando o Windows Form e trabalhar com Web Form ou MVC. Essa experiência para mim não está sendo boa, não só por esse caso, mas fico meio perdido.

Comment: Dê um exemplo (código) de como tu usas essa propriedade `ItemIndex`. Ai fica mais fácil entender o que tu queres fazer.